# Semicolon at the ends of if-statements and functions in C

Tags: c

I just ran into some code that overuse semicolons, or use semicolon for different purposes that I am not aware of.

I found semicolons at the end of if-statements and at the end of functions. For instance:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    // some code

    if (x == NULL) {
        // some code
    };  <-----

    // more code

    return 0;
}; <---
```

It is compiling with cc, not gcc. 
What do those semicolons do? I'm assuming that there is no difference because the compiler would just consider it as empty statement.

Comment: The semi-colon after the end of the function is plain wrong.  If 'cc' is accepting it, it must be treating it as some sort of empty global declaration - but it is plain bogus.  The other semi-colon has been explained well.

Comment: 'gcc' will warn about the semi-colon at the end if you use the '-pedantic' flag. 'cc' depends on your platform but it's often just a soft link to 'gcc' so you might want to try it or take a look at 'man cc'.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They do nothing. They're a sign of someone who doesn't understand the language terribly well, I suspect.

If this is source code you notionally "own", I would remove the code and try to have a gentle chat with the person who wrote it.

Comment: We used to see this quite a bit many years back when we had a team of programmers move from Turbo Pascal to C.  In Pascal, you need the semi-colon after 'End' in most circumstances, and the programmers incorrectly brought the semi-colon with them.  Once the habit forms, it sticks.

Answer (score 7):

that's dummy statememt. You sample is identical to

```
if (x == NULL) {
 // some code
 do_something_here();
}

/* empty (dummy statement) here */ ;

// more code
some_other_code_here();
```

Comment: You gave a better example than you thought. "// some code" should be "// empty here" because it IS empty and because 0 dummy statements are as legally valid as 1 dummy statement.

Comment: I'm following his example, that's why there's "some code" - he must have something in his real code.

Answer (score 5):

You are right, the compiler considers them empty statements. They are not needed, I guess the programmer somehow thought they were.

Answer (score 2):

The first semicolon (after the if-statement) is just an empty expression which does nothing. I fail to see any point of having it there.

The second semicolon (after the function) is an error since it is outside of any block of code. The compiler should give a warning.

Comment: Nope. No warning with cc. That's why I thought this piece of code is bizarre.
Maybe if I run this through lint, it would throw error/warnings.

Comment: I thought the C standard allowed external declarations with no contents.  In other words, bizarre but legally bizarre.  Maybe I'd better check again.

Comment: Windows Programmer, it's C++ that allows an optional semicolon after a member function definition. But neither C nor C++ allow them to appear after a ordinary function definition, to my knowledge

Comment: I'm not sure, but section 6.7 "Declarations" of the C standard says "A declaration shall declare at least a declarator (other than the parameters of a function or 
the members of a structure or union), a tag, or the members of an enumeration."
I interpret that as if a semicolon alone doesn't count as a declaration.

Comment: Furthermore, with Pedantic Warnings on, GCC says "ISO C does not allow extra ';' outside of a function.

Comment: @Federico: I was talking about cc without any option. I am aware of the pedantic option, but I was just curious because I thought the compiler without any option should've taken care of this type of errors.

Comment: Federico's quotes clinch it for the second semicolon. Since the second semicolon isn't part of a valid declaration it must be a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

These semicolons are not needed (as you said, they are empty statements). Your code compiles with gcc, providing that 'x' is defined (check http://www.codepad.org). There's no reason why a C compiler would refuse to compile your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the author may have been going for something like:

```
if(condition for tbd block)
    ;
else {
    //Some code here
}
```

which you might do if you were scaffolding code and still wanted it to compile. There's a good chance that it's just an error as Jon suggests though.

Answer (score 0):

These semicolons are useless as others have pointed out already. The only thing I want to add is that IMO, these are optimized out anyway i.e., compiler doesn't generate any real code for these.