# equals with strings is producing wrong results

Tags: java, string, if-statement, equals

i have a simple function inside a class that checks if two strings are equal ( this is for a hangman game). The code is simple, with two class variables:

```
    private String hiddenWord;
    private String dashWord;



public void compareGuessWord(String clientGuess) {
        if (clientGuess.length() > 1) {
                System.out.println("Kollar om dashord: " + dashWord);
                System.out.println("Kollar om hidden: " + this.hiddenWord);
                System.out.println("Kollar om guess:" + clientGuess);

            if (clientGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(this.hiddenWord));
            {
                this.dashWord = clientGuess;  
            }
                System.out.println("SECOND Kollar om guess:" + clientGuess);
                System.out.println("SECOND Kollar om dashord: " + dashWord);
                System.out.println("SECOND Kollar om hidden: " + hiddenWord);
        }
    }
```

Here is the console output, which u can see that it is running the inner if even though they dont match.
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3eMp.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semicolon at the ends of if-statements and functions in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846804/semicolon-at-the-ends-of-if-statements-and-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`if (clientGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(this.hiddenWord));` Your `if` does nothing but checking. Remove the `;` after it.

Answer (score 3):

In your if condition have ';' so that if is not working

```
if (clientGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(this.hiddenWord))**;**
            {
                this.dashWord = clientGuess;  
            }
```

The compiler consider it as a normal statement, so remove semicolon ";" and check

Answer (score 2):

your If Statement is getting terminated as you had put semicolon at the end

```
if (clientGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(this.hiddenWord));
```

remove the semicolon and it will work fine